# How do i add whitepsaces to a String while filling it up in a for-loop in Bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

Have a string as follows:

```
files="applications/dbt/Dockerfile applications/dbt/cloudbuild.yaml applications/dataform/Dockerfile applications/dataform/cloudbuild.yaml"
```

Want to extract the first two directories and save it as another string like this:

```
"applications/dbt applications/dbt applications/dataform pplications/dataform"
```

But while filling up the second string, its being saved as

```
applications/dbtapplications/dbtapplications/dataformapplications/dataform
```

What i tried:

```
files="applications/dbt/Dockerfile applications/dbt/cloudbuild.yaml applications/dataform/Dockerfile applications/dataform/cloudbuild.yaml"

arr=($files)
#extracting the first two directories and saving it to a new string
for i in ${arr[@]}; do files2+=$(echo "$i" | cut -d/ -f 1-2); done

echo $files2
```

files2 echoes the following

```
applications/dbtapplications/dbtapplications/dataformapplications/dataform
```

Comment: It's very likely your code would be better if you don;t create that `files` scalar variable in the first place and use an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing your code as much as possible:

(assuming to only remove the last right part):

```
arr=( applications/dbt/Dockerfile applications/dbt/cloudbuild.yaml applications/dataform/Dockerfile applications/dataform/cloudbuild.yaml )
#extracting the first two directories and saving it to a new string
for file in "${arr[@]}"; do
    files2+="${file%/*} "
done
```

```
echo "$files2"
applications/dbt applications/dbt applications/dataform
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for loop` as requested

```
for dir in ${files}; 
  do file2+=$(printf '%s ' "${dir%/*}")
done
```

which will give output

```
$ echo "$file2"
applications/dbt applications/dbt applications/dataform applications/dataform
```

However, it would be much easier with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~([^/]*/[^/]*)[^ ]*~\1~g' <<< $files
applications/dbt applications/dbt applications/dataform applications/dataform
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string in an array first. Assuming there are no white/blank/newline space embedded in your strings/path name. Something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files="applications/dbt/Dockerfile applications/dbt/cloudbuild.yaml applications/dataform/Dockerfile applications/dataform/cloudbuild.yaml"

mapfile -t array <<< "${files// /$'\n'}"
```

Now check the value of the `array`

```
declare -p array
```

Output

```
declare -a array=([0]="applications/dbt/Dockerfile" [1]="applications/dbt/cloudbuild.yaml" [2]="applications/dataform/Dockerfile" [3]="applications/dataform/cloudbuild.yaml")
```

Remove all the last `/` from the path name in the array.

```
new_array=("${array[@]%/*}")
```

Check the new value

```
declare -p new_array
```

Output

```
declare -a new_array=([0]="applications/dbt" [1]="applications/dbt" [2]="applications/dataform" [3]="applications/dataform")
```

---

Now the value is an array, assign it to a variable  or do what ever you like with it. Like what was mentioned in the comment section. Use an array from the start.

---

Assign the first 2 directories/path in a variable (weird requirement)

```
new_var="${new_array[@]::2}"
```

```
declare -p new_var
```

Output

```
declare -- new_var="applications/dbt applications/dbt"
```